# Vieta's formulas for factoring quintic polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

given the following polynomial ,

$x^5 −20x^3 +37x^2 +12x−44$

Is it possible to factor it using the Vieta's Formula ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If our polynomial has integer root then $44$ is divisible by these roots.

Easy to see that $2$ and $-1$ they are roots and we can get the following factoring.

$$x^5 −20x^3 +37x^2 +12x−44=$$
$$=x^5+x^4-x^4-x^3-19x^3-19x^2+56x^2+56x-44x-44=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^4-x^3-19x^2+56x-44)=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^4-2x^3+x^3-2x^2-17x^2+34x+22x-44)=$$
$$=(x-2)(x+1)(x^3+x^2-17x+22)=$$
$$=(x-2)(x+1)(x^3-2x^2+3x^2-6x-11x+22)=$$
$$=(x-2)^2(x+1)(x^2+3x-11).$$

Comment: thanks ! , i'm more interested in the way you done it.

Comment: @james I added something and I am ready to explain more.

Comment: thanks again , is there any general approach for factoring 5th degree polynomial ?

Comment: No, james! It's an easiest case only. Factoring of fifth degree polynomial in the  general case it's hard enough. For example: $x^5+x^4-12x^3-21x^2+x+5.$

Comment: thanks a lot , it would be perfect if you could add any relative-to-the-subject links , explaining the polynomial problems and the different ways to approach them !

Comment: I have no something specific. You can search it in the net.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69068/discussion-between-james-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $x=2$ and $x=-1$ are integer solutions